# C program: pass function as parameter to another function to create thread

Tags: c, function, pthreads

I would need some help. I been doing it for hours and is not able to get it to work. Generally, I have a function which access a kernel Driver and I would like to pass that function as a parameter to another function that include some pthread code. I researched and found out that I may need a function pointer.

Here is the function which I want to pass as a parameter.

```
static void kernelTest(char Send[BUFFER_LENGTH])
{
    int fd = open("/dev/kernelTest", O_RDWR); 
}
```

Here is the function which I want to pass in:

```
static void createKThread(void (*f)(char *))
{
  pthread_t t1;
  int ret;
  ret =  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, (*f)(char), NULL);
  pthread_join(t1, NULL);
}
```

I attempted the function pointer but it is giving me error.

```
 error: expected expression before ‘char’
```

I greatly appreciate any help rendered. Thank You!

Comment: `pthread_create(&t1, NULL, f, NULL);` would be correct, but the prototype of the function pointer should be `void *(*)(void *)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(*f)(char)` is invalid syntax.  It looks like you're attempting to call the function `f` and passing `char` as a parameter, which you can't do.

Since you're not actually calling `f`, just pass it to `pthread_create` directly:

```
ret =  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, f, NULL);
```

There's still a problem with this, however.  The third parameter to `pthread_create` is expected to be of type `void *(*)(void *)`, i.e. a pointer to a function that has a `void *` parameter and returns a `void *`.  Your function has type `void (*)(char *)`, so the parameters are incompatible.

You need to either change the signature of `kernelTest` to match what `pthread_create` expects:

```
static void *kernelTest(void *param)
{
    char *send = param;
    int fd = open("/dev/kernelTest", O_RDWR); 
    return NULL;
}
```

Or you need to create a wrapper function which matches `pthread_create`:

```
static void *kernelTest_wrapper(void *param)
{
    char *send = param;
    kernelTest(send); 
    return NULL;
}
```